# Removed partitions from SSD

Tags: linux, partition, data-recovery

I accidentally removed 2 or 3 partitions from my main disk (SSD) which were related to windows (I'm dual booting Mint and Win 10). I stopped myself as soon as I realized that I'm working on the wrong drive (I was trying to remove partitions from an internal HDD).

The system is still running, how can I recover the partitions I accidentally removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you've only removed partitions, and not written anything to the space formerly taken by the partitions, you can re-created the partitions. Just take care to only re-create the partitions and not also create a filesystem on them or otherwise format them. You need to rewrite the partition table only.

You can do that even if you've rebooted the system, but it may be more difficult to find out the necessary information.

To re-create a partition, you need to know:

- Its start position. This is absolutely required. If you get it wrong you won't be able to access any data.
- Its size. If it's too large, you'll just waste space. If it's too small, be careful: it may appear to work casually, but then lead to horrible data loss later.
- Possibly its type. Linux mostly doesn't care about partition types, but Windows does. Fortunately, if you know what OS and what usage the partition has (e.g. filesystem, swap, encrypted volume, …), that determines the partition type.
- Possibly its number. The partition number determines the number in `/dev/sdz99` in Linux and the driver letter in Windows.

Beware of rounding in offsets and sizes, and of the differences between decimal and binary unit prefixes, e.g. 1,000,000 bytes (1 MB, decimal) vs. 2<sup>20</sup>=1,048,576 bytes (1 MiB, binary). I recommend using `fdisk` and specifying sizes in 512-byte sectors, because all sizes and offsets are multiples of 512 bytes whereas larger units introduce a risk of rounding.

Under Linux, you can find the location of the partitions the kernel knows about from files in `/sys/block`. If the kernel is still using some of the old partitions, then it won't have been able to re-read the partition table after you modified it, so that's still the old information. The unit is 512-byte blocks. For example:

```
$ cat /sys/block/sda/sda2/start    
14680064
$ cat /sys/block/sda/sda2/size 
2097152
```

This shows partition number 2 starting at the offset 14680064*512 bytes (7 GiB), of size 2097152*512 bytes (1 GiB).

If you can't figure out where the partitions started, you can use a tool that will go and search for them. [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) includes this functionality. You can install it on Mint (there's a Debian package) or run it from a liveCD/liveUSB. A live run is pretty much necessary when you want to recover deleted files, but if you just deleted a partition from the partition table, you can keep using your system normally. Run `testdisk` with one argument, the disk where you want to recover partitions, and use the “Analyse” menu.

Do make sure that the proposed partitions look sensible. The tool may find false positives, especially but not exclusively locations of former partitions that you'd deleted before today.

Once you think you've recovered a partition, make some sanity checks:

- `file -s /dev/sdz99` should tell you that `/dev/sdz99` contains the kind of filesystem or other volume that you expect.
- Run `tune2fs -l` on ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystems, `ntfsinfo` to probe NTFS filesystems, etc.
- Run `fsck -n` on the filesystem. It should complain loudly if the partition ends before the filesystem (but I'm not sure whether this is the case for all filesystem types).